# Batching / combing requests in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have an AngularJS application that has a lot of directives which are populated from nested nodes in AJAX requests. For example I might get a response like:

```
{
  name: "Blog post title",
  comment_ids: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Currently in my controller, I will make a request to load data for each of the child nodes comments and populate them onto the scope. Something like:

```
_.each(comment_ids, function(id) {
    scope.comment_data[id] = $http.get(id); // psuedocode for the $get
});
```

I then use the data on the page like:

```
<comment data="comment_data.1"></comment>
```

This works great but I'm thinking about converting my directives to take an id instead of an object and to handle loading the data themselves. The problem I face is that I might get multiple requests to the same endpoint if the same directive is present on the page multiple times, e.g.

```
<comment id="1"></comment>
<comment id="1"></comment>
<comment id="1"></comment>
```

This is going to result in three calls to the comments endpoint. Given this:

**Will the browser batch multiple calls to the same HTTP endpoint into one request if it occurs in small space of time, or should I write an interceptor to handle doing it myself?**

Comment: like caching? if the end point is identical, you could use the `cache` attribute of `$http`, which stores and retrieves things in/from local storage

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This problem is now solved quite elegantly with: https://github.com/facebook/dataloader

> DataLoader is a generic utility to be used as part of your
>   application's data fetching layer to provide a consistent API over
>   various backends and reduce requests to those backends via batching
>   and caching.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 1):

I would move the $http calls to their own service.  The benefit is you can use it in a service or controller as needed and as many times as necessary--this is especially useful if you use any kind of JS-controlled caching.

I'm developing an AngularJS oData service for SharePoint 2010/2013 REST calls that uses localStorage to cache results and only fetches updates from the server.  This works especially well when I'm calling the same data over and over, it is just fetched from localStorage without ever making the HTTP call.

```
// Pseudo code to put in a service
var persistentCache = function (query) {

    return localStorage[query] ? {
        'then': function (callback) {
            callback(JSON.parse(localStorage[query]));
        }
    } : $http(query).then(function (resp) {
        return localStorage[query] = JSON.stringify(resp);
    });

};
```

Alternatively, you could use a module design pattern to cache your calls just for the life of the app and only fetch if it is not in the app cache.

```
// Pseudo code to put in a service
var appOnlyCache = (function () {

    var _cache = {};

    return function (query) {

        return _cache[query] ? {
            'then': function (callback) {
                callback(JSON.parse(_cache[query]));
            }
        } : $http(query).then(function (resp) {
            return _cache[query] = JSON.stringify(resp);
        });

        };

}());
```

Both examples with more robunst implementation with compression & error handling can be found in the AngularSharepoint service I've working on for an app right now: [AngularSharepoint](https://github.com/jeff-mccoy/Field-Training-Support-System/blob/master/Code/app/scripts/angular-sharepoint.js)

Comment: $http are in their own service, actually instanced from a resource factory which provides my own wrappers around $resource calls.

I'm kind of leery around trying to keep my own local version of the cached objects. It kind of takes away the ability for the API to set caching rules and moves them to the client. Also makes it hard when to know to invalidate the local cache.

Comment: Perhaps I could just fetch from the local cache if the call was made within 5 seconds, then after that invalidate the local cache. This is coming back to my original idea of batching the requests (although I would only batch if their was an outstanding http request being made).

Comment: Local cache works for me because I use a timeout field to only get changes for a given query and merge the rest with the cache.  This is a huge bandwidth savings for my app.  I do app caching too for some things because they don't change often but don't want them to waste localStorage space either.  Batching + some temp cache sounds like your best bet.